# When exactly to ask for Runtime Permission?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, permissions, android-permissions

Since [Runtime Permissions](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html?hl=es#behavior-runtime-permissions) were introduced in Android Marshmallow, I've been meaning to apply the new way for requesting permissions and I've read and understood the dangerous permissions and how to check for them and request them.

The question is, If I have an `Activity` that contains a `Button` for opening Camera. 
**Do I check and request the permission when the Activity is opened? Or when the button is clicked?**

Please explain why your suggested way is preferred.

Comment: Request the permission when the button is clicked

Comment: while opening that  activity or before that you can give.. But once give permissions on main activity.. or app startup activity.. so that it will no more ask every time... if you give on click it may struck so that before that you need to give

Comment: @NongthonbamTonthoi can you please explain why this is preferred than requesting it in the Activity?

Comment: @Don'tBenegative I can control the button to skip asking for permission if it was rejected the first time. and If I ask for the permission in the Activity, would it be normal that the user grants a permission then he doesn't use the feature anyway?

Comment: yes if user deny permission simple give exit app on deny....  once if they are present they are saved... if you deny close app

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Do I check and request the permission when the Activity is opened? Or when the button is clicked?

If the only purpose of the `Activity` is to take a picture when the button is clicked, I would request the permission when the activity is opened.

If the `Activity` has other roles, such that the take-a-picture button is only one feature out of many, I would ask for the permission when the user clicks the button.

In other words, once the user has requested to go down a path that will (almost) certainly need the permission, ask for the permission.

Answer (score 2):

According to me, **when click on button ask for permission to open camera**.

because activity can have many component which can request for like camera, contacts, write storage, etc

> **so you must not ask for permission when activity opens but when you click on button ask for camera permission**

*if you want to send SMS than ask when you need to send not at opening of activity.*

[Permissions Best Practices.](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/permissions/best-practices.html)

You can download official sample app [here](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/samples/RuntimePermissions/index.html).

hope you get it.

Answer (score -1):

Starting from Android SDK 23, system permissions are divided into two categories, normal and dangerous:

- Normal permissions do not directly risk the user's privacy. If your
  app lists a normal permission in its manifest, the system grants the
  permission automatically.
- Dangerous permissions can give the app access to the user's
  confidential data.

If your app lists a normal permission in its manifest, the system grants the permission automatically. If you list a dangerous permission, the user has to explicitly give approval to your app.

For more information, see [Normal and Dangerous Permissions](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/permissions.html#normal-dangerous).

> If your app targets API 23, and you need to ask user for a dangerous
>   permission (such as READ_CONTACT or READ_CALL_LOG etc.), you need to
>   ask for permission in runtime.

Comment: The question is about where in the app flow he should ask.