# Attach a pdf to email, grant permission

Tags: android, android-intent, file-permissions, email-attachments, outputstream

If I grant `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission all works good, but can I get it to work without asking? It worked without It on my emulator, but on a real device it doesn't work without it.

**Output stream**

```
String fileName = "Körjorunal_" + lastUpdateTime + ".PDF";
String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();

File file = new File(path, fileName)
pdfUri = Uri.fromFile(file);

OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
document.writeTo(outputStream);
document.close();
outputStream.close();
```

**Intent**

```
// Gets invoked on setup,
mShareIntent = new Intent();
mShareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
mShareIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
mShareIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);

// Creates document type.
mShareIntent.setType("application/pdf");

// Going via email:
mShareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Körjournal i bifogad PDF");

// Attach the PDf Uri.
mShareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, pdfUri);

mShareActionProvider.setShareIntent(mShareIntent);
```

**Manifest**

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FLAG_GRANT_*_URI_PERMISSION` (for `READ` and `WRITE`) really are for where the `Uri` is from your own `ContentProvider`. If you want to avoid the need for the `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` (and superfluous `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`) permission:

Step #1: Write the file to [internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/07/storage-situation-internal-storage.html), such as `getCacheDir()`

Step #2: Serve that file from internal storage using `FileProvider`

Step #3: Use your existing `ACTION_SEND` logic, substituting the `Uri` that you get from `FileProvider`

You will see that pattern used in [this sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/ContentProvider/V4FileProvider). My sample is for `ACTION_VIEW`, not `ACTION_SEND`, but otherwise it is a close match.

One key difference, though, will be in how you grant the permissions, if your `minSdkVersion` is below 21. `Uri` values in extras were ignored by `FLAG_GRANT_*_URI_PERMISSION` on Android 4.4 and below. For those versions, the only solution that I know of is to manually grant rights to every possible app (in your case, every PDF viewer).

In [this sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Camera/FileProvider), I use `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` to take a picture, and I use a `FileProvider` `Uri` for that (since `file` `Uri` values are [going away](https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/03/14/psa-file-scheme-ban-n-developer-preview.html)). Just as you are using `EXTRA_STREAM` with a `Uri`, I am using `EXTRA_OUTPUT`, and so I run into the same `Uri`-in-an-extra permission problem. And, so, I go through all this mess:

```
  i.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputUri);

  if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
  }
  else {
    List<ResolveInfo> resInfoList=
      getPackageManager()
        .queryIntentActivities(i, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);

    for (ResolveInfo resolveInfo : resInfoList) {
      String packageName = resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName;
      grantUriPermission(packageName, outputUri,
        Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION |
          Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    }
  }

  startActivityForResult(i, CONTENT_REQUEST);
```

(here, `i` is my `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` `Intent`)

So, I grant any `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`Intent`the rights to work with this`Uri` on Android 4.4 and older.

Comment: Thanks what I was looking for, I have to go through both of those.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the feature without the permission.

If you are using an Android version prior to Marshmallow, you can just add the permission to the Manifest and it won't ask for it again.

But Marshmallow categorized permissions into [Normal and Dangerous permissions](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/permissions.html#normal-dangerous). You have to ask for dangerous permissions just before the user uses the feature.

Comment: Okey thanks, If I ask for the permission when the user press the  mShareActionProvider.setOnShareTargetSelectedListener, The permission will be asked inside the the shareprovider at the same time, how could I stop this  without asking for permission already inside onCreate()?

Comment: you first ask for permission, then if and only if the permission is granted, show the share provider.

Comment: I mean is it possible to add the permission check when the user press the onCreateOptionsMenu() and not before?

Comment: Yes, you can ask for permission any time. check [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37523025/when-exactly-to-ask-for-runtime-permission) that I posted regarding this matter. All you need is to apply [the code](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html) where you find fit.